# How to use Twilio Client in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am creating an app in which i require to implement Click To Call facility. So for communication I am using ***Twilio Client***. I have tried [this example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript).

Now all i need it i need to implement the same in my Angular 2 application. How can i import ***Twilio Client*** in my Typescript and how can i make use of it?

I am trying to import Twilio in my component like

```
import * as Twilio from 'twilio'
```

but this is not correct method to import it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. Right now we don't have any TypeScript bindings and therefore bundling like that won't work. I'm working on some bindings but in the mean time I would suggest you include the library like it's done in the demo application using a script tag. You can use our Twilio CDN for it:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script>
```

Afterwards you have to let TypeScript know about it. For this you currently have to use `declare const`. Unfortunately this won't give you any of the neatness of TypeScript's type-checking until the bindings are done but it at least let's you use it. Just add the following line in the file where you are planning to consume the Twilio code:

```
declare const Twilio: any;
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Dominik

Comment: One thing i am looking for is App to App calling functionality. I am not getting any solution for that.

Comment: Hey Ronak! Check out the Twilio Client quickstart. This one works for both calling from the client to real phone numbers but also to other clients.

Comment: You can find the code here: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-node.
The import part are these lines on the server side: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-node/blob/master/index.js#L34-L54

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: Any news about the typescript version? Thanks!

Comment: @Eusthace As of now no. Haven't heard of anything about that.

Comment: Can you pls tell me, how can we make use of Twilio constant variable  which i declared in my component in an angular2 application?

Comment: I have the same problem, is there any news about the typescript version?

Comment: @dunkendel , I did the same as you suggest but always get undefined
declare const Twilio: any;

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
    private chatClient: any;

    subscribedChannels: any;

    constructor () {
        console.log(Twilio);
        console.log(Twilio.Chat);
        this.chatClient = Twilio.Chat.Client;
    }

Comment: @dkundel Is there any updates on Twilio and typescript binding. Can I import twilio in my typescript now? BTW I'm using Angular5

Comment: Hey @sayedsaad. Yes Twilio Chat is written in TypeScript by now so you should be able to just use it. Here is an example application that uses it: https://github.com/angular-berlin/ngry-chat/blob/master/src/app/core/twilio-chat.service.ts

Comment: @dkundel Hi, is there any updates on Twilio Voice and typescript binding? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Now, when you install Twilio Client Library from npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-chat), it has corresponding type definitions, so you can just write `import { Client, User } from "twilio-chat";`, then declare a `Client`variable in your component `twilioClient: Client` and create it:

```
Client.create(token).then(client => {
        this.twilioClient = client
});
```

Unfortunately there are no d.ts for twilio-common, so if you want to use something from it, like AccessManager, you need to do this like this, with all variables having `any` type:

```
let AccessManager = require('twilio-common').AccessManager;
let accessManager = new AccessManager(token);
```

EDIT: unfortunately, for some reason started getting responses for missing d.ts modules from 'twilio-chat' in dependent files, so it looks like this lib is not ready for using with TS yet:(.

Comment: has there been any progress on this yet?