# Twilio Chat in Angular2 application

Tags: typescript, angularjs-directive, twilio, angular2-template, twilio-programmable-chat

I was trying to add a ***TWILIO Chat*** in my Angular2 application. I got a solution for importing TWILIO into our component from this link - [How to use Twilio Client in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480191/how-to-use-twilio-client-in-angular-2) .

While consoling the `Twilio` variable, which i got from `declare const Twilio: any;`, i am getting the entire twilio function. Can anyone please tell me how can i actually implement a chat application or how can i make use of that function, in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Now that you have the `Twilio` variable, you can access the chat functions through the `Twilio.Chat.Client` object.

I recommend reading through the [Twilio Programmable Chat documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/) to see how it all works together and how you can build your own chat application. You can also check out the [example application](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node), which isn't built in Angular, but should give you an idea of how things should work together.

Comment: what about Angular+NativeScript? ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687363/using-twilio-chat-with-nativescript-and-angular ). I can't find any example out there. My guess was that it should have worked, it is JavaScript in the end, and I'm not using dom/browser/window stuff. `twilio-chat` works fine in Electron+Angular, but not on NativeScript+Angular. I really don't know what else I can try to make `twilio-chat` work.

Comment: I don't know much about NativeScript myself. From a cursory glance, I don't believe web sockets are supported out of the box and they are pretty fundamental to Chat, so I would look into that. I'm not aware of any examples out there though.